# angular UI-Router: ui-sref-active on child element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I give an child element of an `ui-sref` anchor the `ui-sref-active` class?

I tried to do this in my menu on all anchors:

```
<a ui-sref="some.route">
    <h2 ui-sref-active="selected">CLICK HERE</h2>
</a>
```

but it doesn't work. I'm new to Angular, so could someone maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqLtoQpLM2I0aiC5nXvG?p=preview)

As stated in the doc:

**[`ui-sref-active`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active)**

> ...
>   ui-sref-active can live on the same element as ui-sref **or on a parent** element. The first ui-sref-active found at the same level or above the ui-sref will be used.
>   ...

we need the parent (or current) element. So this will work:

```
<li ui-sref-active="selected">
    <a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="selected">
    <a ui-sref="parent">parent</a></li>
<li  ui-sref-active="selected">
    <a ui-sref="parent.child">parent.child</a></li>
```

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqLtoQpLM2I0aiC5nXvG?p=preview)

Comment: Great to see that, Steve! Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)